Generar informe de ausencias en columnas por día
La cuestión es la siguiente.
Imaginemos una tabla con la siguiente información:

Necesitaría una consulta, o varias en SQL Server, trabajo con la versión 2019, que dentro de un período de tiempo me pueda agrupar por días y motivos mostrando un resultado como el siguiente:

Muchas gracias.
jachguate Sorry.
Yo he intentado realizar esto como una consulta de referencias cruzadas o pivot, pero el resultado no es el que deseo. Os muestro la consulta que realicé y el resultado.
SELECT TrabaMotivo, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6],[7], [8], [9],[10], [11], [12],[13], [14], [15],[16], [17], [18],[19], [20],[21],[22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27],[28], [29], [30],[31]
FROM (
SELECT au.TRABAJADOR + '-' + au.MOTIVO TrabaMotivo, 
       DAY(au.FechaFin) Dia, SUM(1) Contador
FROM AUSENCIAS au 
WHERE au.FechaInicio <= '20240531' AND au.FechaFin >= '20240501'
GROUP BY au.TRABAJADOR, au.MOTIVO, DAY(au.FechaFin)
)
V PIVOT (SUM(Contador) FOR Dia IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6],[7], [8], [9],[10],[11], [12],[13], [14], [15],[16], [17], [18],[19], [20], [21],[22], [23], [24],[25], [26], [27],[28], [29], [30], [31])
                         ) AS PT

Y esto es lo máximo que he podido conseguir:

Evidentemente no es lo que deseo.
Decía que igual el resultado habría que obtenerlo en varias consultas porque como veis las fechas se añaden como un intervalo, FechaInicio y FechaFin, y en el resultado cada día del intervalo quiero que aparezca el concepto. O sea, si el trabajador 1 se va de vacaciones desde el 1 al 5 de mayo, quiero que en las columnas 1,2,3,4,5 me aparezca el trabajador 1.
No sé si queda claro.
De cualquier forma muchas gracias por vuestras sugerencias e interés.

Queres una tabla pivotante... ya sabes por donde buscar ;)

A lo mejor tambien se puede con CASE WHEN

Tener los títulos de las columnas como fechas es algo que requiere de código dinámico por lo que no recomiendo que lo hagas en SQL. Por lo menos hasta que lo comprendas correctamente.

Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.

Esto no es una tarea para SQL. En SQL usamos y producimos tablas relacionadas. Tu resultado espectado contiene la primera fila que muestra TRABAJADOR01-VA con TRABAJADOR03-VA y TRABAJADOR04-VA. Pero en realidad no tienen una relación. Solamente es que se encuentran en esta fila porque decides que poner TRABAJADOR01-VA como el primero en la columna 1. Por ejemplo, sería posible poner TRABAJADOR02-AP en vez, porque también está en columna 1. Es arbitrario. No estoy diciendo que no es posible crear tan resulta en SQL, pero es una tarea para una aplicación, no para SQL.

Hay varias piezas que son esenciales para resolver este problema y explicar a detalle cada una de ellas haría demasiado larga esta entrada, por lo que voy a resumir el tema lo más posible y quizás dejar algunas referencias a otras respuestas donde lo he explicado más a detalle.
También vamos a simplificar el problema. La solución que voy a dejar no trabaja con cualquier rango arbitrario de fechas. Está diseñada para devolver información dentro de un mismo mes calendario. Esto se puede generalizar, pero es una tarea que queda al AP.
Los puntos importantes a saber son:

La solución se va construyendo a través de distintos CTEs. No es la única manera de hacerlo y probablemente no sea la más eficiente, pero la prefiero, pues divide la tarea en pequeños pasos que son, generalmente, fáciles de comprender.

Dado que quieres individualizar los días de ausencia de cada trabajador, necesitas convertir la tabla que tienes con fecha inicio y fecha fin, en una tabla donde haya una fila por cada fecha de ausencia del trabajador, con su motivo. Para resolver este problema, nos podemos valer de:

Poner la fecha de inicio y fecha final de la consulta en un par de variables
Un generador de números consecutivos, hay varias maneras de hacer esto en SQL Server, no entraré en detalles, simplemente usaré una de las que sé. Es el CTE Numeros de la consulta.
Con el generador de números y las variables de fechas, generamos al vuelo un registro para cada día que hay entre estas en el CTE Fechas
Finalmente, hacemos un join entre la tabla Ausencias y la tabla de Fechas generada en el paso anterior. Aprovecho este paso para preparar los datos para la salida final, concateno el nombre del trabajador con el motivo de la ausencia e nla columna dato y, de una vez, extraigo el día de la fecha, ya que es el valor con el que se hará el pivoteo final. El resultado de esta operación, para el primer registro de la tabla Ausencias del ejemplo nos va a devolver:

Dato            dia numero
--------------- --- ------
Trabajador1-VA  1   1
Trabajador1-VA  2   1
Trabajador1-VA  3   1


Hay un truco importante en este último CTE, y es la columna numero. La he agregado dado que necesitamos una manera de relacionar registros a la hora de hacer el pivoteo de la tabla. Viendo la salida que se desea, entendí que necesitamos generar un número de fila en el cual colocar cada registro en esta tabla final. Por ello, para númerar, hago particiones por día y dentro de cada partición voy numerando las filas en orden alfabético por el nombre del trabajador y, si hubiera dos trabajadores con el mismo nombre, le sigue el motivo de ausencia, también en orden alfabético. Est
Este es un dato que tiene un propósito meramente funcional y que no debiera quedar en el resultado final que ve el usuario. Yo lo he dejado para que se entienda como he hilado la solución, pero debiera ser removido de la presentación final de los datos. OJO, que no se puede quitar del procesamiento de los datos, pues se perdería la funcionalidad.



Ahora que ya tenemos la tabla de Datos, solo queda hacer el pivoteo final.  Esta consulta pivot es bastante simple, es decir, no hay mucha magia aquí, pero hay también un truco que es importante y que explico a continuación:
Es que la cláusula pivot nos exige el uso de funciones de agregación, pues en realidad está pensada en la creación de resúmenes de información. Nosotros no la estamos resumiendo, solamente le estamos dando vuelta.
Vamos a usar como ejes del pivoteo, verticalmente el numero de fila generado en el CTE Datos y horizontalmente el número de día del mes. A menos que haya errores en la tabla de Ausencias, esto significa que en realidad cada fila de la tabla de Datos tiene valores distintos para estas dos columnas y ocupará una casilla en el resultado final.
Como no podemos saltarnos el requisito de usar funciones de agregación, podemos usar indistintamente min() o max(), que nos van a devolver el mismo valor de la única fila que, en teoría, deben procesar.


Dicho todo esto, el código habla más que mil palabras (vaya, por mucho que he querido resumir, no son mil, sino dos o tres mil, pero igual el código habla más que ellas):
declare @fechaMin date = '20240501';
declare @fechaMax date = '20240531';

with
Numeros as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n from sys.all_objects a
),
Fechas as (
select dateadd(day, n-1, @fechaMin) Fecha from Numeros where n-1 <= DATEDIFF(day, @fechaMin, @fechaMax)
),
Datos as (
select   Ausencias.Trabajador + '-' + Ausencias.Motivo Dato
       , DAY(fecha) as dia
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by day(fecha) order by Ausencias.Trabajador, Ausencias.Motivo) numero
  from Ausencias
       inner join Fechas on Fechas.Fecha between Ausencias.FechaInicio and Ausencias.FechaFin
)
select numero, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
  from Datos p
 pivot (min(Dato) for dia in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) pvt
 order by numero

Con los datos de la tabla de entrada de la pregunta, produce este resultado:
numero               1              2              3              4              5
-------------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
1                    Trabajador1-VA Trabajador1-VA Trabajador1-VA Trabajador3-VA Trabajador4-VA
2                    Trabajador2-AP Trabajador2-AP Trabajador3-VA Trabajador4-VA NULL
3                    Trabajador3-VA Trabajador3-VA Trabajador4-VA Trabajador6-AP NULL
4                    Trabajador4-VA Trabajador4-VA Trabajador5-AP NULL           NULL

(4 rows affected)

fiddle
Algunas observaciones finales:

La consulta solo procesa 5 días, ya que es lo que pide el ejemplo de la pregunta. Se puede extender el pivot muy fácilmente a 31 días, que cubre cualquier mes.

No se hace ninguna validación sobre las fechas de inicio y fin, pero si abarcan más de un mes, la consulta va a fallar, pues va a mostrar en la columna 1, las ausencias del 1 de cada mes que abarque la misma.

El número de días que se pueden generar está limitado por la cantidad de filas en la tabla sys.all_objects. En una base de datos nueva esta suele tener unos 2000 registros, lo que cubriría un período de unos 6 años.

No se hacen validaciones ni correcciones sobre los datos de la tabla Ausencias, se asume que los registros no tendrán traslapes ni duplicidad.

La consulta está hecha como un ejemplo del que puedas partir. No he puesto mayor esfuerzo en hacerla eficiente.
Para producción, yo colocaría por allí algún where que de entrada traiga solo los registros relevantes de la tabla de Ausencias, para comenzar. Vería los planes y me aseguraría que la tabla subyacente tenga los índices necesarios para filtrar y ordenar los registros, si es que alcanza el optimizador a utilizarlos.
Si no lo hace, tomaría los pasos que hoy son CTE's y evaluaría la creación de tablas temporales sobre las que pueda crear índices que ayuden a un buen desempeño e incluso llegaría a evaluar otras acciones, como la creación de una vista materializada e indexada con los datos del join de fechas con ausencias, por decir un ejemplo.



Olvidé mencionar que esta consulta tiene la ventaja que podrías llegar a usarla sin modificaciones para cualquier mes. Ya a nivel de UI puedes ajustar para que se muestren solamente las columnas de los días que realmente tiene el mes, que llegarán a 28, 29, 30, 31 según sea el caso. Por tanto, no requiere la generación de SQL dinámico. Con pasar los valores de las fechas como parámetro o modificarlas en el texto del script tienes suficiente.

Cuando he visto el resultado me he puesto nervioso, joder aún lo estoy. Muchísimas gracias es justo lo que necesitaba. De verdad, no sé como agradecértelo. Gracias, gracias.

Con cervezas podría ser, jajaja :D.
